# Which way is the best way to grant read access to a remote database-server?

Tags: mysql, database, ssh

I have a question for you stackers. I'm not so well renowned with server maintenance and admin configuration. My problem is that I wan't to grant read access for a user to my mySQL databases on a remote server that's hosted by a server company.

I'm connecting via ssh to my server and then trying to create a new user for the databases in root -> mysql.

The problem I'm having is that I cannon't seem to connect to the databases from any other ip than as a localhost on the server itself. The bin-adress in my.cnf is pointing to localhost.

Is there another way to do this? Or rather how do you do this?

I really appreciate your answers.

Comment: there are many software like workbench or sqlyog are available through which you can connect to db.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Log in to your remote server via SSH
2. Open the the my.cnf file in an editor. (On Ubuntu that is located at
   /etc/mysql/my.cnf): `sudo vi /etc/mysql/my.cnf`
3. Find the `bind-address` setting under the `[mysqld]` section and
   change it from `localhost` to your the public IP address of your
   server.
4. Save your edit.
5. Restart MySQL: `sudo service mysql restart`

Grant access to the remote user by logging into mysql as root and executing these commands (obviously you'll need to replace the IP address, database name and remote username with the correct values):

```
mysql -u root -p mysql
mysql> update db set Host='999.999.999.999' where Db='MyDB';
mysql> update user set Host='999.999.999.999' where user='RemoteUsername';
mysql> exit;
```

More information can be found [on this page](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/how-do-i-enable-remote-access-to-mysql-database-server.html).